# How to get text for below XML using selenium

Tags: selenium

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<button class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">
<span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
</button>
Please enter valid Member ID
</div>
```

Hi All, 
I have to print the "Please enter valid Member ID". But when I'm trying to use below line of code, value is printing as

×
Please enter Member ID

```
String Error_Message=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'][@role='alert']")).getText().trim();

System.out.println(Error_Message);
```

Please suggest.

Comment: my friend ur responses should always be in comments and not as answers..please rectify this before SO moderators start marking you

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath:-

```
//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' and @role='alert']/text()[2]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: HinThe given selector //div[@role='alert']/text()[2] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@role='alert']/text()[2]" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Text]]. It should be an element

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur suggestion but I got the below error.  "HinThe given selector //div[@role='alert']/text()[2] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@role='alert']/text()[2]" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Text]]. It should be an element – Sindu just now   edit   
"

Answer (score 0):

If you go and see the `innerHtml` of `div` element. You will see 2 child. One is your `x` symbol and the other one is your desired text.

So basically you need to identify the text element not the `x` character so you have to find the text and then switch to its second element. This is how you can do it:-

```
//div[@role='alert']/text()[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly locate div and use getText() on it as belows:

```
WebDriver browser=WebDriverFactory.getDriver("file:///C:/Users/Desktop/test.html");
System.out.println(browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible']")).getText());
```

**Output**

```
Ã— Please enter valid Member ID
```

Then just do some string processing and that should do away with the garbage character